# AtomicLong concurrency output not as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, atomic-long

I was running the following example, expecting the output to be `1000` always but I get `999` sometimes as well. I believe the output should always be `1000` or am I missing something here?

```
public class AtomicTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Counter counter = new Counter();
        int count = 1000;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
        
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {counter.inc();});
        }
        
        executorService.shutdown();
        
        System.out.println(counter.getValue());
        
    }

}

class Counter {
    private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    
    public void inc() {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
    
    public void dec() {
        counter.decrementAndGet();
    }
    
    public long getValue() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it for more than 20 times and there is no 999. How many times am I expected to run this to see 999?

Comment: You are not waiting for the tasks to finish.

Comment: It says i have types in my question..i don't get why my question was downvoted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDoc for [`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.

You are not using `awaitTermination`. You're not waiting for the tasks to complete.